# How to convert specific attribute into element

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert specific XML attribute into XML element.
The input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<filter query="select" name="some name"/>
```

My desire output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <filter name="some name">
    <query>select</query>
</filter>
```

I'm using the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/filter/@query">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However when I apply this XSLT to the provided example the name attribute disappears:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filter>
    <query>select</query>
</filter>
```

If I change the attributes ordering, i.e. put 'name' before 'query' everything works perfectly.
I try to solve it but my XSLT knowledge is very limited. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the required output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- match the filter element -->
   <xsl:template match="filter">
     <!-- output a filter element -->
     <xsl:element name="filter">
       <!-- add the name attribute, using the source name attribute value -->
       <xsl:attribute name="name">
         <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <!-- add the query child element, using the source query attribute value -->
       <xsl:element name="query">
         <xsl:value-of select="@query"/>
       </xsl:element>
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @ColinE. It works, but adds xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" attribute which causes to JAXB failure. Do have any idea how to remove it?

Comment: Fixed ... that was in your original transform! Please upvote / accept ;-)

Comment: additional question. How should I change the XSLT in order to handle nested elements in source XML, i.e. the source XML looks like:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<filter query="select" name="some name">
   <returned-attributes>
        <returned-attribute>id</returned-attribute>
        <returned-attribute>name</returned-attribute>
    </returned-attributes>
</filter>

Comment: Please create a new question for this.

Comment: I think all you need to do is add `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` to the template matching the **filter** element, so that any existing child elements are copied across.

Comment: @SashaK: The wanted transformation can be twice as short as the accepted answer -- have a look at my answer for a better XSLT coding style.

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite shorter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[not(name()='query')]"/>
     <query><xsl:value-of select="@query"/></query>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:

```
<filter query="select" name="some name"/>
```

the wanted, correct output is produced:

```
<filter name="some name">
   <query>select</query>
</filter>
```

Comment: Just because it is shorter, it does not mean it is better! I prefer XSL transforms that resemble their output, these are easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @ColinE: This solution is not only shorter but much simpler and this matters. Avoiding unnecessary complex code results in more understandable and maintainable solutions that are produced with less effort. One example of completely unnecessary complexity in your answer is using `xsl:element` for creating an element (`filter`) whose name is statically known. The same goes for creating its `name` attribute using an `xsl:attribute` instruction. Thank you for letting us know about your preferences...

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre Novatchev. It works for the provided example, the problem is that my "real" XML is more complicated and it does not work with provided XSLT. My "real" XML looks like: <filter query="select" name="some name" description="hello">
 <certification>WFA</certification>
 <parameters>
        <parameter type="STRING" name="name" label="name">
            <description>Some name</description>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</filter> The only thing I need to do is to move query attribute to element

Comment: @SashaK: Comments aren't the best format for code -- please, either update your current question with your more realistic XML and wanted result, or, better, ask a new question. As for the current question, it is completely answered and two solutions are provided at present, one of which isn't bad.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev. I've opened new question - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713246/how-to-convert-specific-attribute-into-element-in-complex-xml)

Comment: @SashaKorman: Please, see my answer. The other answer has a small error that could result in deleting all `query` attributes in the XML document, whereas only the `query` attribute of the `filter` element needs to be deleted.