# How to convert specific attribute into element in complex XML

Tags: xml, xslt

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710529/how-to-convert-specific-attribute-into-element/) I asked how to convert specific attribute to element in simple XML. Now I have more complex input.
I need to transform the attribute 'query' into an element.
Complex input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<filter query="select" name="hello" description="world">
    <certification>WFA</certification>
    <uuid>fd5d9f15-f6d9-4e71-aaf4-024aaaa627f2</uuid>
    <parameters>
        <parameter type="STRING" name="name" label="name">
            <description>Some name</description>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
    <returned-attributes>
        <returned-attribute>id</returned-attribute>
    </returned-attributes>
</filter>
```

My desire output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<filter name="hello" description="world">
    <certification>WFA</certification>
    <uuid>fd5d9f15-f6d9-4e71-aaf4-024aaaa627f2</uuid>
    <query>select<query/>
    <parameters>
        <parameter type="STRING" name="name" label="name">
            <description>Some name</description>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
    <returned-attributes>
        <returned-attribute>id</returned-attribute>
    </returned-attributes>
</filter>
```

I use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match the filter element -->
    <xsl:template match="filter">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/filter/@query">
                <!-- output a filter element -->
                <xsl:element name="filter">

                    <!-- add the name attribute, using the source name attribute value -->
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <!-- add the description attribute (if found), using the source name attribute value -->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="/filter/@description">
                            <xsl:attribute name="description">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@description"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>

                    <!-- add the query as child element, using the source query attribute value -->
                    <xsl:element name="query">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@query"/>
                    </xsl:element>

                    <!-- add all common elements -->
                    <xsl:element name="certification">
                        <xsl:value-of select="certification"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="uuid">
                        <xsl:value-of select="uuid"/>
                    </xsl:element>

                    <!-- copy parameters -->
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="/filter/parameters"/>
                    </xsl:copy>

                    <!-- copy attributes -->
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="/filter/returned-attributes"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transformation works, but it seems to me to complicated.
Note, that I use if/else logic because my input can contain "old" (not transformed) and 
"new" (transformed) XML files.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a short and simple solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="parameters">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/filter/@query" mode="build"/>
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="/filter/@query"/>

     <xsl:template match="/filter/@query" mode="build">
         <query><xsl:value-of select="."/></query>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<filter query="select" name="hello" description="world">
    <certification>WFA</certification>
    <uuid>fd5d9f15-f6d9-4e71-aaf4-024aaaa627f2</uuid>
    <parameters>
        <parameter type="STRING" name="name" label="name">
            <description>Some name</description>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
    <returned-attributes>
        <returned-attribute>id</returned-attribute>
    </returned-attributes>
</filter>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<filter name="hello" description="world">
   <certification>WFA</certification>
   <uuid>fd5d9f15-f6d9-4e71-aaf4-024aaaa627f2</uuid>
   <query>select</query>
   <parameters>
      <parameter type="STRING" name="name" label="name">
         <description>Some name</description>
      </parameter>
   </parameters>
   <returned-attributes>
      <returned-attribute>id</returned-attribute>
   </returned-attributes>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre Novatchev. It works fine. I've just wrapped query block with "when" logic in order to support old/new XML files.
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/filter/@query">
                <query>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../@query"/>
                </query>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

Comment: @SashaKorman: It is almost always possible to avoid explicit xslt conditional instructions and to use just templates and pattern matching. In this case I'd use: `<xsl:apply-templates select="/filter/@query" mode="build"/>` and will have: `<xsl:template match="/filter/@query" mode="build"><query> <xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>`

Comment: you mean like the following XSLT? It does not work
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/filter/@query" mode="build"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/filter/@query" mode="build">
        <query><xsl:value-of select="."/> </query>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @SashaKorman: I just updated my answer with the solution that satisfies your new requirements -- exactly with the code I proposed in the comment -- and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- copy all content other than the query attribute -->
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[not(name()='query')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- match uuid so that we can insert query after -->
   <xsl:template match="uuid">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
       <!-- add our query element -->
       <xsl:element name="query">
         <!-- navigate up one level to reach the query attribute -->
         <xsl:value-of select="../@query"/>
       </xsl:element>     
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A quick tip for you, learn about the [identity transform](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity) and how it works.

Comment: There is a logical error in the proposed solution. On the given XML document it produces the wanted result, however on other documents that have similar structure it may delete an attribute when this isn't wanted. Please, correct.

Comment: Thanks @ColinE. It works for me. I just have added "when" logic for "query" element creation in order to support already transformed XML files.
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/filter/@query">
                <!-- add our query element -->
                <xsl:element name="query">
                    <!-- navigate up one level to reach the query attribute -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="../@query"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev can you please provide an example where this XSLT can delete attributes

Comment: @SashaKorman: Any XML document like the one you provided, that has a `query` atribute on an element other than the top, `filter` element, and that is not intended to be deleted, too.